# flex-grow on HTML 5 <video> element not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex layout. In this layout I want to dynamically add video elements where each of the elements takes the same space. The thing that is bothering me is that when only one video is present it doesn't take all the free space.

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/25825/

Seems like `flex-grow` is not working.

```js
function change() {

  var video = document.getElementById('videoElement');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  var video = document.createElement("video");
  video.src = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";

  container.appendChild(video);

}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex, flexDirection: row flexWrap: wrap
}
#videoElement {
  flex_grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="container">

</div>



<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a host of syntax errors in your CSS - hence why it's not working.

Try this. https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/25833/

css:

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

#videoElement {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, consider using the correct property names and syntax.

Instead of this:

```
#container {
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: flex,
      flexDirection: row
      flexWrap:wrap
}

#videoElement {
      flex_grow:1;
}
```

Try this:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#videoElement {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

That said, you are still correct, the `flex-grow` property is not stretching the video. Neither are the `width` and `flex-basis` properties, for that matter. In a brief search I couldn't find any documentation about this. It could be a bug.

---

### Alternative Solution

If expanding the video to occupy 100% width is the primary goal, here's an effective method:

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <video src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4"></video>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()">
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ctyrbngr/)